# How to add taxonomies as an argument in wp_query

Tags: wordpress, post

This a part of a program to display a product list. I created the products as custom posts, and I need to display the posts on the basis of taxonomies.

Who can I provide taxonomies as an argument in post selection arguments?

I created taxonomies and posts using tool set plugin.

```
   <?php $taxonomies = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
    'parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => get_query_var('Order', 'ASC'),
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
?><?php 
$i=1;
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {; ?>
<?php
   if(!empty(do_shortcode('[types term_id="'.$taxonomy->term_id.'" termmeta="secondary-category-image" size="product-main-cat" url="true"][/types]'))){
    $pro_cat_img = do_shortcode('[types term_id="'.$taxonomy->term_id.'" termmeta="secondary-category-image" size="product-main-cat" url="true"][/types]');
   }else{
    $pro_cat_img = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/product-guitar.png";
   } ?>

                        <h1>
                          <?php echo $taxonomy->name; 
//$ir=$taxonomy->name;
                          ?>
                        </h1>

                        <ul>

<?php 
            // args
            $args = array(
               'posts_per_page'  => 5,
               'post_type'    => 'product',
               'post_status'  => 'publish',
               //how can i add taxonomies asan argument here
            );
            // query            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $count = $the_query->post_count; 
            if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
             while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
          if(has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {                              
            $feature_image_full = simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'banner_img'));   
            $pr_img_source = $feature_image_full->attributes()->src;

                           ?>
                           <li>
                              <span>
                              <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                              </span>
                           </li>


          <?php } endwhile;  endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        </ul>
```

---

Here is the working code

---

```
<?php $taxonomies = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
    'parent' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => get_query_var('Order', 'ASC'),
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);
?><?php 
$i=1;
if  ($taxonomies) {
  foreach ($taxonomies  as $taxonomy ) {; ?>
<?php
   if(!empty(do_shortcode('[types term_id="'.$taxonomy->term_id.'" termmeta="secondary-category-image" size="product-main-cat" url="true"][/types]'))){
    $pro_cat_img = do_shortcode('[types term_id="'.$taxonomy->term_id.'" termmeta="secondary-category-image" size="product-main-cat" url="true"][/types]');
   }else{
    $pro_cat_img = get_template_directory_uri()."/img/product-guitar.png";
   } ?>

  <div class="product-row clearfix">
                     <div class="bg-box">
                        <?php if($i==1){?>
                        <img src="<?php echo  esc_url($pro_cat_img); ?>" class="product-guitar"/>
                        <?php }else if($i==2){ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo  esc_url($pro_cat_img); ?>" class="product-speaker"/>
                        <?php }else if($i==3){ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo  esc_url($pro_cat_img); ?>" class="product-headphone"/>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( array('cat'=>$taxonomy->term_id), home_url('/products') ) ); ?>" class="view-more-btn button button--moema ">
                        READ MORE
                        </a>
                     </div>
                     <div class="items-list-box">
                        <h1>
                          <?php echo $taxonomy->name; 
$ir=$taxonomy->name;
                          ?>
                        </h1>

                        <ul>

<?php 
            // args
            $args = array(
               'posts_per_page'  => 5,
               'post_type'    => 'product',
               'post_status'  => 'publish',
               'tax_query' => array(
                 array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_category',
                    'field' => 'name',
                    'terms' => $ir,
                        )
                ),

            );
            // query            
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            $count = $the_query->post_count; 
            if( $the_query->have_posts() ):
             while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
          if(has_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID())) {                              
            $feature_image_full = simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(), 'banner_img'));   
            $pr_img_source = $feature_image_full->attributes()->src;

                           ?>
                           <li>
                              <span>
                              <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                              </span>
                           </li>

                  <!-- <img src="<?php //echo esc_url($pr_img_source); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                 -->
          <?php } endwhile;  endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: It would be good to know what resources you've looked at, and what specifically you've tried, AS WELL AS what the name(s) of your taxonomies are (the keys, not the labels).  Have you seen this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/how-do-i-query-a-custom-post-type-with-a-custom-taxonomy or read this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters ? If so, have you tried adding arguments? What arguments did you try adding? What happend when you added them?

Comment: Thanks man it worked , it really means a lot and I'm adding the result as well for future reference for others